# Pandas correlation on just one column containing np arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, correlation

I'm working with a dataframe with a column containing a np.array per row (in this case representing the mean waveform of brain recordings trought the time). I want to calculate the pearson correlation of this column (array by array).

This is my code

```
lenght = len(df.Mean)
Mean = []   
for i in range(len(df.Mean)):
    Mean.append(df.Mean[i])

Correlation_p = np.zeros((lenght,lenght))
P_Value_p = np.zeros((lenght,lenght))

for i in range(lenght):
    for j in range(lenght):
        Correlation_p[i][j],P_Value_p[i][j] = stats.pearsonr(df.Mean[i],df.Mean[j])
```

This works, but I want to know if there is a more pythonic way to do it, maybe using `df.corr()`. I tried but I failed in how to do it.

EDIT: the output of `df.Mean.head()`

```
0    [-0.2559348091247745, 0.02743063113723536, 0.3...
1    [-0.37025615099744325, -0.11299328141596175, 0...
2    [-1.0543681894876467, -0.8452798699354909, -0....
3    [-0.23527437766943646, -0.28657810260136585, -...
4    [0.45557980303095674, 0.6055674269814991, 0.74...
Name: Mean, dtype: object
```

Comment: Do you have a data example of a few rows?

Comment: There. I edited the post.

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, I made a little update to my answer. It should work now, if not let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrays that you would like to correlate seem in single cells of the DataFrame, if I am not mistaken. The following brings it in a format where each single array occupies a single column.
I made an data example that resembles the format of `df.Mean.head()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[np.random.randint(0,5,10), np.random.randint(0,5,10), np.random.randint(0,5,10)]})
```

You can turn these arrays into columns using this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(df['x'].tolist()).transpose())
```

Adapt the reshape parameters according to your own dimensions.
From there, it would be fairly straightforward.

A correlation matrix can be created by:

```
df.corr()
```

A visualization of the correlation matrix:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.matshow(df.corr())
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. Is clearly better than the way I was doing it. Thanks

Comment: One little thing: Using reshape as you do mixes the arrays. In your example, instead of transposing them for create the columns, it cuts the arrays on intervals of 3 and then puts them one below the another. 
I use `df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(df['x'].tolist()).transpose())` instead for transposing the arrays.

Comment: Oops, you are right, I will change that accordingly for future users.